# Why doesn't my custom made linear regression model match sklearn?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, gradient-descent

I'm attempting to create a simple linear model with Python using no libraries (other than `numpy`). Here's what I have

```
import numpy as np

import pandas

np.random.seed(1)

alpha = 0.1

def h(x, w):
  return np.dot(w.T, x)

def cost(X, W, Y):
  totalCost = 0
  for i in range(47):
    diff = h(X[i], W) - Y[i]
    squared = diff * diff
    totalCost += squared

  return totalCost / 2

housing_data = np.loadtxt('Housing.csv', delimiter=',')

x1 = housing_data[:,0]
x2 = housing_data[:,1]
y = housing_data[:,2]

avgX1 = np.mean(x1)
stdX1 = np.std(x1)
normX1 = (x1 - avgX1) / stdX1
print('avgX1', avgX1)
print('stdX1', stdX1)

avgX2 = np.mean(x2)
stdX2 = np.std(x2)
normX2 = (x2 - avgX2) / stdX2

print('avgX2', avgX2)
print('stdX2', stdX2)

normalizedX = np.ones((47, 3))

normalizedX[:,1] = normX1
normalizedX[:,2] = normX2

np.savetxt('normalizedX.csv', normalizedX)

weights = np.ones((3,))

for boom in range(100):
  currentCost = cost(normalizedX, weights, y)
  if boom % 1 == 0:
    print(boom, 'iteration', weights[0], weights[1], weights[2])
    print('Cost', currentCost)

  for i in range(47):
    errorDiff = h(normalizedX[i], weights) - y[i]
    weights[0] = weights[0] - alpha * (errorDiff) * normalizedX[i][0]
    weights[1] = weights[1] - alpha * (errorDiff) * normalizedX[i][1]
    weights[2] = weights[2] - alpha * (errorDiff) * normalizedX[i][2]

print(weights)

predictedX = [1, (2100 - avgX1) / stdX1, (3 - avgX2) / stdX2]
firstPrediction = np.array(predictedX)
print('firstPrediction', firstPrediction)
firstPrediction = h(firstPrediction, weights)
print(firstPrediction)
```

First, it converges VERY quickly. After only 14 iterations. Second, it gives me a different result than a linear regression with `sklearn`. For reference, my `sklearn` code is:

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
import pandas
import sklearn
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

dataset = pandas.read_csv('Housing.csv', header=None)

x = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 2].values

linearRegressor = LinearRegression()

xnorm = sklearn.preprocessing.scale(x)
scaleCoef = sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(x)
mean = scaleCoef.mean_
std = numpy.sqrt(scaleCoef.var_)
print('stf')
print(std)

stuff = linearRegressor.fit(xnorm, y)

predictedX = [[(2100 - mean[0]) / std[0], (3 - mean[1]) / std[1]]]
yPrediction = linearRegressor.predict(predictedX)
print('predictedX', predictedX)
print('predict', yPrediction)


print(stuff.coef_, stuff.intercept_)
```

My custom model predicts 337,000 for the value of y and sklearn predicts 355,000. My data is 47 rows that look like

```
2104,3,3.999e+05
1600,3,3.299e+05
2400,3,3.69e+05
1416,2,2.32e+05
3000,4,5.399e+05
1985,4,2.999e+05
1534,3,3.149e+05
```

Complete data available at https://github.com/shamoons/linear-logistic-regression/blob/master/Housing.csv

I assume either (a) my regression with gradient descent is somehow wrong or (b) I'm not using `sklearn` properly.

Any other reasons why the 2 wouldn't predict the same output for a given input?

Comment: Can you provide a copy of your data please?

Comment: I added a link to the complete data set

Comment: I think the linear regressor is based on scipy.linalg.lstsq, which uses lapack gelsd driver (svd to solve the least square problem). I think because you are using gradient descent and not the same algorithm, they may be leading to different weights and hence different predictions.

Comment: @plasmon360 can I make the scikit use a gradient descent?

Comment: @Shamoon I think you can use stochastic gradient regressor (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDRegressor.html#sklearn.linear_model.SGDRegressor) It is similar to gradient descent, but differs in the way the gradient are calculated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are missing the 1/m term (where m is the size of y) in the gradient descent. After including the 1/m term, I seem to get a predicted value similar to your sklearn code.

see below

```
....
weights = np.ones((3,))

m = y.size
for boom in range(100):
  currentCost = cost(normalizedX, weights, y)
  if boom % 1 == 0:
    print(boom, 'iteration', weights[0], weights[1], weights[2])
    print('Cost', currentCost)

  for i in range(47):
    errorDiff = h(normalizedX[i], weights) - y[i]
    weights[0] = weights[0] - alpha *(1/m)* (errorDiff) * normalizedX[i][0]
    weights[1] = weights[1] - alpha *(1/m)*  (errorDiff) * normalizedX[i][1]
    weights[2] = weights[2] - alpha *(1/m)* (errorDiff) * normalizedX[i][2]

...
```

this gives the firstprediction to be 355242.

This agrees well with the linear regression model even though it does not do gradient descent.

I also tried sgdregressor (uses stochastic gradient descent) in sklearn and it too seem to get a value close to linear regressor model and your model. see the code below

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
import pandas
import sklearn
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression, SGDRegressor

dataset = pandas.read_csv('Housing.csv', header=None)

x = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 2].values

sgdRegressor = SGDRegressor(penalty='none', learning_rate='constant', eta0=0.1, max_iter=1000, tol = 1E-6)

xnorm = sklearn.preprocessing.scale(x)
scaleCoef = sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(x)
mean = scaleCoef.mean_
std = numpy.sqrt(scaleCoef.var_)
print('stf')
print(std)

yPrediction = []
predictedX = [[(2100 - mean[0]) / std[0], (3 - mean[1]) / std[1]]]
print('predictedX', predictedX)
for trials in range(10):
    stuff = sgdRegressor.fit(xnorm, y)
    yPrediction.extend(sgdRegressor.predict(predictedX))
print('predict', np.mean(yPrediction))
```

results in

```
predict 355533.10119985335
```

Comment: Why would I have a `1/m` term in the gradient descent?

Comment: Because ur cost function is adding over all the 47 points or m points. So when u take the gradient u will get the 1/m part. See the final update rules at http://mccormickml.com/2014/03/04/gradient-descent-derivation/